# Animations producing intel_drm errors

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, assimp

I'm working on implementing animations within my model loader which uses Assimp; C++/OpenGL for rendering. I've been following this tutorial: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html extensively. Suffice it to say that I did not follow the tutorial completely as there were some bits that I disagreed with code-wise, so I adapted it. Mind you, I don't use none of the maths components the author there uses, so I used glm. At any rate, the problem is that sometimes my program runs, and on other times it doesn't. When I run my program it would run and then crash instantly, and on other times it would simply run as normal.

A few things to take into account:

1. Before animations/loading bones were added, the model loader worked completely fine and models were loaded without causing no crash whatsoever;
2. Models with NO bones still load just as fine; it only becomes a problem when models with bones are being loaded.
3. Please note that NOTHING from the bones is being rendered. I haven't even started allocating the bones to vertex attributes; not even the shaders are modified for this.
4. Everything is being run on a single thread; there is no multi-threading... yet.

So, naturally I took to this bit of code which actually loaded the bones. I've debugged the application and found that the problems lie mostly around here:

```
Mesh* processMesh(uint meshIndex, aiMesh *mesh)
{
    vector<VertexBoneData> bones;

    bones.resize(mesh->mNumVertices);

    // .. getting other mesh data

    if (pAnimate)
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumBones; i++)
        {
            uint boneIndex = 0;
            string boneName(mesh->mBones[i]->mName.data);
            auto it = pBoneMap.find(boneName);

            if (it == pBoneMap.end())
            {
                boneIndex = pNumBones;
                ++pNumBones;
                BoneInfo bi;
                pBoneInfo.push_back(bi);
                auto tempMat = mesh->mBones[i]->mOffsetMatrix;
                pBoneInfo[boneIndex].boneOffset = to_glm_mat4(tempMat);
                pBoneMap[boneName] = boneIndex;
            }
            else boneIndex = pBoneMap[boneName];

            for (uint j = 0; j < mesh->mBones[i]->mNumWeights; j++)
            {
                uint vertexID = mesh->mBones[i]->mWeights[j].mVertexId;
                float weit = mesh->mBones[i]->mWeights[j].mWeight;
                bones.at(vertexID).addBoneData(boneIndex, weit);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the last line the author used a `[]` operator to access elements, but I decided to use '`.at` for range-checking. The function `to_glm_mat4` is defined thus:

```
glm::mat4 to_glm_mat4(const aiMatrix4x4 &m)
{
    glm::mat4 to;

    to[0][0] = m.a1; to[1][0] = m.a2;
    to[2][0] = m.a3; to[3][0] = m.a4;
    to[0][1] = m.b1; to[1][1] = m.b2;
    to[2][1] = m.b3; to[3][1] = m.b4;
    to[0][2] = m.c1; to[1][2] = m.c2;
    to[2][2] = m.c3; to[3][2] = m.c4;
    to[0][3] = m.d1; to[1][3] = m.d2;
    to[2][3] = m.d3; to[3][3] = m.d4;

    return to;
}
```

I also had to change VertexBoneData since it used raw arrays which I thought flawed:

struct VertexBoneData
{
    vector boneIDs;
    vector weights;

```
VertexBoneData()
{
    reset();

    boneIDs.resize(NUM_BONES_PER_VERTEX);
    weights.resize(NUM_BONES_PER_VERTEX);
}

void reset()
{
    boneIDs.clear();
    weights.clear();
}

void addBoneData(unsigned int boneID, float weight)
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < boneIDs.size(); i++)
    {
        if (weights.at(i) == 0.0) // SEG FAULT HERE
        {
            boneIDs.at(i) = boneID;
            weights.at(i) = weight;
            return;
        }
    }
    assert(0);
}
```

};

Now, I'm not entirely sure what is causing the crash, but what baffles me most is that sometimes the program runs (implying that the code isn't necessarily the culprit). So I decided to do a debug-smashdown which involved me inspecting each bone (I skipped some; there are loads of bones!) and found that AFTER all the bones have been loaded I would get this very strange error:

**`No source available for "drm_intel_bo_unreference() at 0x7fffec369ed9"`**

and sometimes I would get this error:

`Error in '/home/.../: corrupted double-linked list (not small): 0x00000 etc ***`

and sometimes I would get a seg fault from glm regarding a vec4 instantiation;

and sometimes... my program runs without ever crashing!

To be fair, implementing animations may just about be harsh on my laptop so maybe it's a CPU/GPU problem as in it's unable to process so much data in one gulp, which is resulting in this crash. My theory is that since it's unable to process that much data, that data is never allocated to vectors.

I'm not using any multi-threading whatsoever, but it has crossed my mind. I figure that it may be the CPU being unable to process so much data hence the chance-run. If I implemented threading, such that the bone-loading is done on another thread; or better, use a mutex because what I found is that by debugging the application slowly the program runs, which makes sense because each task is being broken down into chunks; and that is what a mutex technically does, per se.

For the sake of the argument, and no mockery avowed, my technical specs:

```
Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
Intel i5 dual-core
Intel HD 5500
Mesa 10.5.9 (OpenGL 3.3)
Programming on Eclipse Mars
```

I thus ask, what the hell is causing these intel_drm errors?

Comment: When I wrote this tutorial I used an NVIDIA GPU. We need to understand whether the problem is related to the MESA driver (either a driver bug or something on the application side which may not have been implemented correctly but somehow passes on NVIDIA). Any chance you can take this code and run it on NVIDIA? Also, did you try running it with GDB?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a machine that has an NVIDIA GPU (I used to). But this is what's interesting; I encapsulated the bone-loading code into its own function called `loadBones(..)` and then I put it inside a thread within the `if (pAnimate)` condition. What's interesting is that the amount of crashes I get has been reduced considerably.  But, it can still crash; so it's safe to say that it might be a CPU/GPU issue or just a mere lack of multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reproduced this issue and found it may have been a problem with the lack of multi-threading when it comes to loading bones. I decided to move the loading bone errata into its own function as prescribed in the foresaid tutorial. What I later did was:

```
if (pAnimate)
{
    std::thread t1[&] {
        loadBones(meshIndex, mesh, bones);
    });
    t1.join();
}
```

The lambda function above has the `[&]` to indicate we're passing everything as a reference to ensure no copies are created. To prevent any external forces from 'touching' the data within the `loadBones(..)` function, I've installed a mutex within the function like so:

```
void ModelLoader::loadBones(uint meshIndex, const aiMesh *mesh, std::vector<VertexBoneData> &bones)
{
    std::mutex mut;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);

    // load bones
}
```

This is only a quick and dirty fix. It might not work for everyone, and there's no guarantee the program will run crash-less.

Here are some testing results:

```
Sans threading & mutex: program runs 0 out of 3 times in a row

With threading; sans mutex: program runs 2 out of 3 times in a row

With threading & mutex: program runs 3 out of 3 times in a row
```

If you're using Linux, remember to link `pthread` as well as including `<thread>` and `<mutex>`. Suggestions on thread-optimisation are welcome!